# Sleeve for hose tunnel

Tags: hoses

I would like to install some drip irrigation in a plant bed in the front of my house. Getting it tied into the sprinkler system is not an option here for reasons I won't go into. However, we do have a hose bib fairly close by but there is a concrete walkway between it the plant bed. We are going to be replacing the walkway soon so we will have an opportunity to run the hose over to the plant bed. I'm thinking I'd like to install some kind of sleeve under the new walkway to make a tunnel for the hose. That way maybe I can replace the hose in the future should the need arise.

We're not talking about a great distance here, maybe 5 or so feet. The material would have to be flexible enough to bend under the walkway but rigid enough to hold its shape under ground.

Does anyone know of a product or material that would work here? Maybe a thin walled PVC pipe?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put hose inside the "casing" , I would suggest 2" PVC pipe, common , cheap. But you will need to get to the ends so that you can push the hose through with no turns , only very gradual curves.It will likely need to be much longer than the width of the sidewalk for gradual curve to the surface. Alternatively, just put in 1/2 " PVC with fittings ( 90 degree elbows , adapters to hose at each end,etc.).

Comment: I was thinking about this an a more flexible alternative: https://www.homedepot.com/p/HydroMaxx-2-in-x-10-ft-White-PVC-Schedule-40-Flexible-Pipe-2201200010/310383439?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-310383437-_-310383439-_-N

Comment: Looks difficult to push a hose through; Maybe put the hose in to it before you bury it .

Comment: That's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

For this "conduit" use any PVC pipe in a straight length (eg 40mm). Shove rags and either wire or scrap hose in the end before burying so doesnt fill with concrete and can be found. Then later, excavate each side of the path and it will be easy to pass hose though.